# Why does my django app keep givin me "getattr(): attribute name must be string" error?

Tags: python, django

How do I get the default image as an argument in creating a profile? My Django keeps getting an error highlighting me getting User and me trying to use the image.

this is part of `views.py` in question

```
user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'],
                    email=request.POST['email'],
                    password=request.POST['password1'])
user.is_active = False
user.save()
url = static('default-pfp.jpg')
profile = Profile.objects.create(owner=user, profilePicture=url)
```

There is lines I get highlighted in error

```
TypeError at /profile/signup/

getattr(): attribute name must be a string

1. profile = Profile.objects.create(owner=user, profilePicture=url)
2. user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
```

My static picture is located in static/blog/default-pfp.jpg. I also tried adding blog/ in my URL. I'm also using a docker and nginx here

Full view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.db import ProgrammingError
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.templatetags.static import static


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'signup.html', {'error': 'Username has already been taken ☹️'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                if User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).exists():
                    return render(request, "signup.html",{'error': "This email is already used "})
                else:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'],
                                                    email=request.POST['email'],
                                                    password=request.POST['password1'])
                    user.is_active = False
                    user.save()
                    url = static('default-pfp.jpg')
                    profile = Profile.objects.create(owner=user, profilePicture=url)

                    
                    #auth.login(request, user)
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('activate.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = user.email
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')

            
        else:
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'error': 'Passwords must match'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        # return redirect('home')
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!' + user)

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user=user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'username or password is incorrect.'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def profile(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile':user})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Profile not found ☹️")

def edit(request, username):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('signup')
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if user == request.user:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(owner=user)
            return render(request, 'edit.html', {'profile':user , 'profilechange':profile })
        else:
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile':user})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Profile not found ☹️")
```

Full error

```
TypeError at /profile/signup/

getattr(): attribute name must be string

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:1337/profile/signup/
Django Version:     4.0.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

getattr(): attribute name must be string

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py, line 475, in update_dimension_fields
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     3.9.6
Python Path:    

['/usr/src/app',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 10 Oct 2022 10:10:55 +0000
```

Comment: you're trying to set the default image to the profile?

Comment: Can you share the entire view and full exception?

Comment: @HemalPatel yes

Comment: better define like this in model
`profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/', default="profiles/user-default.png")` then you dont have assign in view function unless you're setting other picture to profile. directory will be like this `static/images/profiles`

Comment: Can you also share `Profile` model, the [update_dimension_fields()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6402b064a9a9c7ed9afc87800a7011b449e29dd0/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L446)  gives the error as per the exception you shared.

Comment: @HemalPatel thanks a lot :) that actually really much better. could you, please, also help me with one more question? how do I reference default="" to a static file?

Comment: default reference to static files? sorry, I don't understand? can you explain?

Comment: @HemalPatel im sorry it took me so long to reply, i've been ill recently. Im trying to pull image from STATIC_URL to be default image of a newly created profile. Your method works really good, but by default, my model is looking for image in MEDIA_URL, while I want to pull image from static. Or maybe I should just put my default picture into MEDIA folder? But it seems like a bad practice

Comment: yes its fine just put that default picture in media folder. its one time action so its ok